# Одномерный массив.. помогите пожалуйста исправить программу

Tags: c++

Дан одномерный массив, состоящий из N ￼ вещественных элементов. Найти сумму элементов массива, расположенных между первым и вторым отрицательными элементами.
Формат входных данных:
В первой строке входного файла содержится число N￼ (1<=N<=100￼). Во второй строке даны N￼ вещественных чисел через пробел.
Формат выходных данных:
Выведите в выходной файл искомую сумму с 3￼ знаками после десятичной точки или 0￼, если в заданном массиве меньше 2￼ отрицательных элементов.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    freopen("input.txt", "rt", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "wt", stdout);
    int k = 0, a, b, n;
    float s = 0;
    cin >> n;
    float* c = new float [n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cin >> c[i];

        if (c[i] < 0)
        {
            ++k;
            b = i;
        }
    }

    if (k < 2)
    {
        cout << 0;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            if (c[i] < 0)
            {
                a = i;
            }

            break;
        }

        for (int i = a + 1; i < b; ++i)
        {
            s += c[i];
        }

        cout << setprecision(3);
        cout << s;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Судя по всему, `break` должен выполняться только если условие `if (c[i] < 0)` истинно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы бы пояснили еще, что у вас не так :)

Вот вариант, смотрите:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    freopen("input.txt", "rt", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "wt", stdout);
    int state = -1, n;
    double x, s = 0;
    // double * array;
    cin >> n;
    // array = new double[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cin >> x;
        // array[i] = x;
        switch(state)
        {
        case -1: if (x < 0) state = 0; break;
        case 0:  if (x < 0) state = 1; else s+= x; break;
        }
    }

    if (state < 1)
    {
        cout << "0\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << setprecision(3) << fixed << s << endl;
    }
    // delete[] array;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В контестере выполняется только 8 тестов из 20.. не для всех чисел работает моя программа..

Comment: Ну, а приведенная в ответе как?... В ней массив вообще не нужен :)

Comment: Обязательно условие - это использовать одномерный массив

Comment: В условии этого нет. Он задан - да, но зачем его использовать? И, кстати, у себя добавьте вывод кроме `setprecision` еще и `fixed` - иначе, скажем, 5 выведется как 5, а не как 5.000 - а проверка может на это реагировать...

Comment: Я чуть подправил ответ - если позарез нужен массив, раскомментируйте закомментированные строки...

Comment: спасибо Вам огромное) чрезвычайно помогли)

Comment: Ну, если ответ устроил - помечайте как принятый, закрывайте вопрос...